# WPF Validation Control

Tags: wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo, validationrules

I am new to WPF and trying to implement validation control on submit form.

Can anyone help me. My code doen't show up any error message even if I enter invalid data infect it does nothing.

Here is my code,

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}


public class UserName : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }

    private string username;
    public string _UserName
    {
        get { return username; }
        set
        {
            username = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("_UserName"));
        }
    }
    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (propertyName == "_UserName")
            {
                bool valid = true;
                foreach (char c in _UserName)
                {
                    if (!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
                    {
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!valid)
                    return "The Username can only contain letters and numbers.";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}
```

}
My XAML code is,

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="User Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,37,0,0" Name="UserNameLB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,37,0,0" Name="UserNameTB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="_UserName">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <DataErrorValidationRule></DataErrorValidationRule>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

EDIT: (here's a style I define which shows errors for all `TextBox` controls)
(put it in `Window.Resources`)

This style will then **show** the **error message in a `ToolTip`**

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                    Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Grid>
    <Label Content="User Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,37,0,0" Name="UserNameLB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,37,0,0" 
             Name="UserNameTB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189"
             Text={Binding Path=_UserName, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, 
                   ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true} />    
</Grid>
```

[Source](https://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/)

Comment: I try to edit my XAML code with the one you have suggested but it is same. no update no error message.

Comment: @user735052 `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus` means it will only run the validation when the TextBox loses focus. Change that to `PropertyChanged` if you want it to validate whenever the property changes. Also, the default validation control for a TextBox is a red border around it. It doesn't display the validation error. To make it display the validation error, you need to overwrite the validation template.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say but atleast it should show red border around textbox which I am not able to see when I run my application.

Comment: @user735052: have you changed `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` OR input an invalid char then navigate away from the `TextBox` (so it loses focus)?

Comment: I am bit of confused with WPF now, I tried every single thing which you have suggested but it doesn't show up even red border on tex box, even if I entered invalid char and even if it is null. It doesn't do anything. It doesn't give any error in code also. How to figure out whats want wrong.

Comment: put a breakpoint int your code at `if (propertyName == "_UserName")
` to see if it gets hit. step through your code to see the result.

Comment: I put a break point to check but after running the application when I enter text in text box it does nothing.

Comment: change to: `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` then what?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to put all logic about your validation in a separate class that inherits from class `ValidationRule` and override method `Validate`. Then you can set the message you want to see about the reason of validation failure, like:

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    try
    {
        if (!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
        {
           return new ValidationResult(false,
                                       "The Username can only contain letters and numbers.");
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new ValidationResult(false, "Illegal characters or " + e.Message);
    }
}
```